# Java NIO Selector can select no more than 50 SelectionKeys?

Tags: java, select, nio

I use [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to stress test my hand built file server, it works pretty well for small files(less than 1KB), while when tested with a 1MB file, it does not work as expected.

The following is the result of the test with a small file:

```
neevek@~$ siege -c 1000 -r 10 -b http://127.0.0.1:9090/1KB.txt
** SIEGE 2.71
** Preparing 1000 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege..      done.

Transactions:              10000 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               9.17 secs
Data transferred:           3.93 MB
Response time:              0.01 secs
Transaction rate:        1090.51 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.43 MB/sec
Concurrency:                7.29
Successful transactions:       10000
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.17
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

The following is the result of a test with a 1MB file:

```
neevek@~$ siege -c 1000 -r 10 -b http://127.0.0.1:9090/1MB.txt
** SIEGE 2.71
** Preparing 1000 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:222: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:222: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:222: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:222: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer
```

When `siege` terminates with the above errors, my file server still spins with a fixed number of `WRITABLE` SelectionKey, i.e. `Selector.select()` keeps returning a fixed number, say 50.

With the above tests, it looks to me that my file server cannot accept no more than 50 concurrent connections, because when running the test with small file, I notice that the server `select`s 1 or 2 SelectionKeys, when running with big file, it `select`s up to 50 every time.

I tried to increase `backlog` in `Socket.bind()` with no help.

What could be the cause of the problem?

**EDIT**

More info:

When testing with a 1MB file, I noticed that `siege` terminated with a `Broken pipe` error, and the file server only accepted **198** connections, though I specified 1000 concurrent connections x 10 rounds(1000*10=10000) to flood the server.

**EDIT 2**

I have tested with the following code(a single class) to reproduce the same problem, in this code, I only **accept** connections, I don't **read** or **write**, the `siege` client terminated with `Connection reset` or `Broken pipe` error before connections time out. I also noticed that Selector can only select less than 1000 keys. you may try the code below to witness the problem.

```
public class TestNIO implements Runnable {
    ServerSocketChannel mServerSocketChannel;
    Selector mSelector;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestNIO().start();
    }

    public TestNIO () throws Exception {
       mSelector = Selector.open();
    }

    public void start () throws Exception {
        mServerSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        mServerSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        mServerSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9090));
        mServerSocketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(150000);
        mServerSocketChannel.register(mSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        int port = mServerSocketChannel.socket().getLocalPort();
        String serverName = "http://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + ":" + port;
        System.out.println("Server start listening on " + serverName);

        new Thread(this).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            while (true) {
                int num = mSelector.select();

                System.out.println("SELECT = " + num + "/" + mSelector.keys().size());
                if (num > 0) {
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = mSelector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey key = keys.next();

                        if (key.isValid() && key.isAcceptable()) {
                            accept(key);
                        }

                    }
                    // clear the selected keys
                    mSelector.selectedKeys().clear();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void accept (SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = mServerSocketChannel.accept();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(1000000);
        socketChannel.socket().setKeepAlive(true);
        // since we are connected, we are ready to READ
        socketChannel.register(mSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it all depends on what your hand written code, doesn't it? You shouldn't normally be selecting on OP_WRITE, for example.

Comment: I select on OP_WRITE only when I have something to write, and clear it when I am done writing everything to the channel. The reason that Selector spins is that the client already closed the connection, and I only check the `Connection reset by peer` on the READ part. I should have detected that the client already closed the connection on the WRITE part I think.

Comment: My confusion is why it handles small files pretty well but not for bigger files? looks like it just can't handle a few dozen of concurrent connections.

Comment: Could it be down to HTTP chunking? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: To my understanding, chunking is a functionality that a server offers, the client may be designed to or not to support it. In my situation, the `siege` client only sends the HTTP header(a GET method) for each request. so chunking is not likely the problem. Thanks for you reply anyway.

Comment: It still depends on your code, and you still haven't posted any. I don't know what you're expecting here but StackOverflown can't see your code, isn't a mind reader, doesn't know what you're thinking, ...

Comment: @EJP, Sorry but now I have posted the code, please take a look, thank you!

Comment: Hi, @EJP, please take a look at my **EDIT 2**, you could reproduce the problem easily with that class. I think the problem has been narrowed down to `Server unable to accept too many concurrent connections`.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You're listening at a constant port 9090 then getting the local port to display it, even though it is still 9090 of course. You're configuring accepted sockets into non-blocking mode and also setting read timeouts on them, which only work in blocking mode. You're registering them for OP_READ but never processing OP_READ (isReadable()) events. So you are accumulating all accepted sockets and never closing them because you never read them to discover dropped connections.

Comment: @EJP, the code you see is not what I originally posted, the code above is just for testing how many connections a server socket can accept before it throws exception, so it does not handle either OP_READ or OP_WRITE. For the constant port, yes it does't make much sense as the code shows, but in production environment, I need to pass **0** as port, so a random port will be chosen for me, and I need to get back that port from socket to display.

Comment: I can only comment on the code you post. This code accepts sockets *ad infinitum* so it runs out of sockets. If you have other code, post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may not relate to my code, I run the same test against an nginx server running locally(MacOSX), the same error occurred. So it most likely relates to hardware or the `siege` client.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually related the the default backlog value set for the ServerSocketChannel

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java#138

You can fix the issue by passing the backlog value as a second parameter to the bind method.

mServerSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9090), "backlog value")

Answer (score 0):

Check the ulimit and hard limit of the number of open files (file descriptors)

I'm guessing you're using linux. You can look in limits.conf
    /etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: I already increased the open file limit, I am using Mac, `ulimit -a` gives me this: `core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited`